# Trying to create a button for my website

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a button for my website.
Here's my code:

CSS:

```
.fheader-text {
    text-align: center;
}

.fheader-text h3 {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
    background: #8edd63;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fheader-text">
    <h3>Aphryv</h3>
</div>
```

The problem is that the backgrounds width is 100%. I cant change this with width: 50px or something like that.

Comment: I dont follow... If you want a button, why not use `<button>Click Me</button>`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that there was a <button>

Answer (score 2):

`<div>`s take all the space, make it a `<span>` instead.
After that you can set your desired width.

Comment: In his case, he uses an `h3` inside the `div`. Changing it to `span` doesn't affect the space it takes since `h3` display is `display:block`

Answer (score 1):

Set the h3 to `inline-block`. I think it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>`'s are by default set to `display: block;`, which will span the entire width of the parent container. If you add `display: inline-block;`, you will be able to set a width.

Comment: So this works but now I cant change the position of the tekst? I tried : margin 0 auto, text-algin.

Comment: You should do some reading on the [box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) and [display positions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). It will clear up your confusions and both concepts are vital to any serious css styling.